# Ajax not working in IE11 error code 0x2f78

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, post, error-code

Here is my ajax setup:

```
                $.support.cors = true;
                $.ajax({
                    beforeSend: function ()
                    {

                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "test.cgx",
                    data: hex_str,       
                    dataType: "xml",
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (msg)
                    {

                    },
                    error: function (msg)
                    {

                    }
                });
```

If the data - `hexstr` **smaller than 4 chars** (for example hex_str = "3A") I got the following error (after 1 minute of request pending):

**XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2f78, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002f78.**

This happens only in IE, FF and Chrome can post any data size.
The data I send it's not in XML format it's only Hex data (I need the  `contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8"`  for some other reason).

I'm using Jquery 1.8.2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem,just  put this line in your header,i hope it will work for you

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the URL and query string. It may be very long.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this error, is was because I had a  in my header pointing to a missing css file. I corrected the link, and the error went away.

I suspect it has something to do with microsoft because it only shows up on Edge. Because it reported the missing link from an XMLHttpRequest method, it looked like a network link to the method, and it spits out this network error even though it was missing a local file.

I hope this helps. Errors that show up but don't appear to do any harm, can sometimes be troublesome. Good luck

...ken